# How to add many sub directories with Java files into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

So I feel like this should be simple but I can't figure it out.
I'm grading some basic Java files (i'm a TA), and I have many folders (denoting the student) with some java files in each. I want to just be able to drag it into eclipse and have it automatically know that the folders are essentially like packages and the sub java files be apart of it so that I can run each file individually.

My file structure:

```
Joe
  - q1.java
  - q2.java
Bob
  - q1.java
  - q2.java
Hannah
  - q1.java
  - q2.java
```

Is there any way I would be able to put this in eclipse and be able to run each program individually? There are 40+ folders so I was hoping there was an easy way to accomplish this. Just by dragging and dropping it into the 'src' folder now gives me errors about missing packages.

EDIT: Figured out I could change each students folder to a src folder, but I get a new error:
"Editor does not contain a main type"

Comment: You could on the next assignement demand of them correct packaging - that way you'll be able to simply throw every folder into src directory and have it work

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying yourself, adding the parent as a source folder won't work since this will assume that subfolders match package names. However, you can just mark all folders, right click, Build Path > Add as Source Folder.

Comment: My facourite alternative hack does not work: Add the parent folder, go to the problems view, and batch-apply a quick fix on all "package does not match" compile errors. That fails because Eclipse does not recognize the fact that it could apply this quick fix to all issues in a batch. :-)